# gallery3, using html in form-label

Tags: php, html, forms, kohana

I am trying to modify the register-module for [gallery3](http://gallery.menalto.com/). I added a new element to the form (which is generated by Forge) but want to add a hyperlink to the related label. Unfortunately it is escaped by the script, even a html::mark_clean() didn't help.

Here is my code:

```
$form = new Forge("register/handler", "", "post", array("id" => "g-register-form"));
$group = $form->group("register_user")->label(t("Register user"));

$group->checkbox("accept_terms")->label(html::mark_clean(t(html::mark_clean('I confirm to have read the <a href="%url">terms of usage</a>.'), 
          array("url" => html::mark_clean("http://www.google.de")))))
          ->id("g-accept-terms")
  ->rules("required")
  ->error_messages("accept", t("You have to accept the terms of usage before you may register."));
```

As you may see I've added the mark_clean at different positions for testing purpose.

The result is the following:

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1" name="accept_terms" id="g-accept-terms">
  I confirm to have read the &lt;a href="http://www.google.de"&gt;terms of usage&lt;/a&gt;.
</label>
```

I would like to avoid to change any existing core file.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$group->checkbox("accept_terms")->label(t('I confirm to have read the <a href="http://yourURL.com/" target="_blank">terms of usage</a>.  more text'))
  ->rules("required")
  ->error_messages("accept", t("You have to accept the terms of usage before you may register."));
```

Comment: Sorry but this is definetly not the answer to my question. as I've written at my first post all html is being escaped by the system.